# How to debug AirConsole Unity quick example

Tags: airconsole

I've followed the instructions on http://developers.airconsole.com/#/guides/unity and I am able to start with and without debug view, but it seems that no messages are sent at all (the OnMessage method in the MonoBehaviour class is never called). 
Is there a way to debug this problem?

Comment: AirConsole Unity plugin does not seem to work when started with Visual Studio Debugger. You have to put a `Debug.Log("...");` statement in your C#-script on the server-side. For the client-side you can follow the instructions I marked as answer if you use the mode 'Virtual Controllers' - it will show in the debug console of your web browser. If your testing it with your smartphone, you can use `alert("button-pressed");`.
If you don't get any results on C#-side: Restart Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug the controller by adding console.logs to your controller.html.

Let's assume you have a button element on your controller that calls myButtonFunction.

```
<button id = "myButton" ontouchstart="myButtonFunction()">Send A Message to Screen</button>
```

Then you add a log to the function to see if the button pressing works correctly.

```
var myButtonFunction = function() {
       console.log("myButton was pressed");
       airconsole.message(AirConsole.SCREEN, "button-pressed");
};
```

To see what your controller logs, you need to use the Start Mode 'Virtual Controllers' and open your browser's developer console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made an alert('test') into the function which is executed ontouchstart. It works in simulator + on the smartphone. As I wrote, the C# method given in the introduction (http://developers.airconsole.com/#/guides/unity) is not executed (I can't see any message and it will not break at a debug point in VisualStudio).

`void OnMessage(int from, JToken data) {
     AirConsole.instance.Message(from, "Full of pixels!");
}`

Comment: Do you listen for the event?
This should be in your Awake function (in C#):  

`AirConsole.instance.onMessage += OnMessage;`

Compare your code with the messaging functions in ExampleBasicLogic.cs to make sure nothing is missing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used the example at (http://developers.airconsole.com/#/guides/unity) where it is the Start() method. I've put a break-point in the OnMessage() method.
`void Start() {
    AirConsole.instance.onMessage += OnMessage;
}

void OnMessage(int from, JToken data) {
    AirConsole.instance.Message(from, "Full of pixels!");
}`

Comment: I've used the cs-file from the example from Github. At the beginning it worked, and then it stopped working. I adjusted my code and it no longer worked. I've used other examples, they worked, I made my changes and it no longer worked. I was looking for mistakes in the code. But that's not the problem. After many hours I've come up with the following solution:  

- If it does not work, restart Unity. 
- If it works and then suddenly no longer works, restart Unity.
- Visual Studio break points may reduce the working time.

Comment: Possible reason: Kaspersky Internet Security Javascript Injection  https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=316466